# Visual Studio cannot load project file -- thinks there's a "ghost" path

Tags: path, visual-studio-2015, projects-and-solutions

There's one weird project in my solution that doesn't want to load.

The error message that VS gives is:

> The project file could not be loaded. Could not find file 'C:\Some Path\Project Name\Project Name\Project Name.csproj'.

Now, the actual path should be `C:\Some Path\Project Name\Project Name.csproj`.

Note how the last part of the path was duplicated. I can't figure out why VS insists on this.

Even weirder, the path that is shown in the properties window is correct. The path in the Solution file is correct.

I've removed all `*.suo` and `*.user` files in the project.

I've cleared caches, restarted VS (countless times), got the latest from TFS, pretty much every possible fix I can come up with. No change.

If I remove the project and try to re-add it, I get the same error. It hasn't always done this (started after a complex merge), but the current branch is getting the same issue on other teammate's computers, too.

**What is causing this incorrect path and how do I fix it?**

Comment: Have you found a solution? :/

Comment: If anyone still has this issue, deleting the hidden .vs folders inside your solution folders and reloading the solution fixed this for me.

Answer (score 0):

edit in the path in the solution file solved the same problem

Comment: Are you referring to Calum's comment: *"deleting the hidden .vs folders inside your solution folders and reloading the solution"* ?